# How to reset Rectangle Grid Tool in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

I pressed some keys (<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>) while holding the mouse and making a grid using the Rectangle Grid Tool. It changed the width of the columns/rows (see image). Now I don't know how to reset it. I want all even columns/rows.

[image: Rectangle Grid Tool]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Double-click** the **Rectangular Grid Tool** in the **Toolbar**.

You can set the options there, or remove what is problematic.

These are the defaults.....

[image]